# Which html5 tag provides the most semantic wrapper for skiplinks?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

An some existing html4 fragment:

```
<body>
    <div id='skiplinks'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#content'>skip to main content</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='bg'>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='main'>
```

What is the most semantic html5 replacement for the semantics free  wrapper?

Comment: I would have to say `<nav>` would be your best choice.

Comment: The html5 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-nav-element) says:  "User agents (such as screen readers) that are targeted at users who can benefit from navigation information being omitted in the initial rendering, or who can benefit from navigation information being immediately available, can use this element as a way to determine what content on the page to initially skip and/or provide on request."  Wouldn't a screen reader skipping the skip links make them useless?  Unless I am misinterpreting the spec?

Answer (score 0):

The [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) is the right choice.

The part about screen readers you quoted in the comments means: screen readers might offer a function to jump to (or ignore) `nav` elements. If all screen readers would implement something like this, you wouldn't have to provide skip links yourself anymore (unless for other use cases/user agents, e.g. mobile).

And yes, that could also mean that a screen reader might skip your skip navigation ;) But obviously this screen reader has the ability to skip implemented then, so your skip navigation is not needed anyway.

The users have (and should have) the control. If they configure their user agents so that they ignore `nav` elements (and only jump to them resp. read them when invoking a certain command), it's their choice. You do your best by semantically marking-up your content, and the users configure their user agents so that they do the job that is required for each users' use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, quite useful.  I have one reservation, though. Skip navigation is obviously used to bypass loads of junk navigation. Junk, that is, for users that must read a linearised page, such as those using screen readers.  I have a friend who uses one, so I find it interesting to ask him how he browses. He uses skiplinks not only to bypass navigation lists, but also all the drivel (marketing bull, etc.) that get loaded into page banners and early in pages, etc.  He says he always appreciates a skiplink that just takes him straight to the content, no nonsense.

Comment: @ppjm: I don't understand … did I claim something different? It depends on page markup, what can be skipped by jumping to the main content, because pages order sections differently (some have main content first, then navigation, then secondary content etc.). On a "typical" 3 column website I always add two skip links: "Jump to content" and "Jump to navigation".